# Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ws/rs/core/Application

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, restlet

I have developed RESTful web service and use org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.createApplication to load class javax.ws.rs.core.Application.
However it threw this Exception:Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ws/rs/core/Application
This is the dependency:

```
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>j2ee6</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/j2ee6.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This jar file is under /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/
And my project run with jdk11 & wildfly22
I don't know why this error happed, anyone can help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.createApplication to load class javax.ws.rs.core.Application.". Can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: Try here: https://gitter.im/restlet-framework/community

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Thanks for your advice, I resolved this problem by downloading j2ee6.jar from remote repository. for wildfly22 may not support j2ee6.jar

Comment: WildFly 22 is a Java EE 8/Jakarta EE 8 server.